# Clear out remnant LDF log files of Sharepoint DB not visible on SBS 2008 Domain Server?

Tags: sql-server, transaction-log, delete, logs, sharepoint

Typical ways for dealing with LDF files that take up a lot of space, recommend these processes to shrink/ eliminate the drive space being occupied.

http://www.sharepointboris.net/2008/10/sharepoint-config-database-log-file-too-big-reduce-it/ and [Link](https://web.archive.org/web/20210121185921/http://geekswithblogs.net/RogueCoder/archive/2008/06/03/122588.aspx)

As an example of following these steps for `SBS Monitoring` database visible in **Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio Express** GUI whose path location on disk is: `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL.1\MSSQL\Data` (this path not shown in screenshot)

I followed these commands on the GUI:
`DB: SBSMonitoring > Tasks > Delete > Log files` and gain about 1-2 GB space.

One the other hand, I find the Sharepoint related DB files under path (shown in screenshot):
`C:\Windows\SYSMSI\SSEE\MSSQL.2005\MSSQL\Data`
But, this database is not visible in **Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio Express** GUI.

I've looked at several answers and tutorials on how to clear out the LDF via GUI and SQL commands, but that is assuming the DB is visible.

What steps can I take to properly clear out the LDF log files for this DB?

Do I have to first add/ connect to it via the SQL GUI?
Or clear out without adding via SQL commands?
Or clear it out with simple file delete in explorer {not recommended from what I read most places}?

This is what I'm reading so far, but haven't found a way to add/ access that DB via those Files and then use above mentioned steps & guides.

Screenshot of files, location & DBs in **Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio Express** GUI:

[image]

**Update:** Adding more information about SQL instances running based on answer, and requesting update to answer on how to add/ access & flush this DB instance.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

I have never used SharePoint or worked with its databases specifically, but both links in your question indicate that you should be able to see, and work with, SharePoint databases in SQL Server Management Studio.

The fact that you cannot see them in your particular case most likely means that they are hosted by a different server instance – not the `...SBS\SBSMONITORING` one you are connected to, according to your screenshots. If you do not know the name of the instance hosting your SharePoint databases, try looking it up in SQL Server Configuration Manager → SQL Server Services.

Once you have found out the name and connected to the right SQL Server instance, you should be able to follow the instructions you have discovered on the Web. But please read the answers on this question first to make sure you understand what you are doing and what the consequences may be:

- [Why Does the Transaction Log Keep Growing or Run Out of Space?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/29829/why-does-the-transaction-log-keep-growing-or-run-out-of-space)

Comment: Thank you for pointing the right direction, I updated the question with information I found in SQL Server Services - Based on that how do I add/ connect to the said Sharepoint DB? Could I request you to update & add to the answer with the next steps :) That would really help.

Comment: @AlexS: As I said, I've never worked with SharePoint. A quick lookup gave me this article, which might have some useful information for you: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Internal_Database